# How to make webview fit into screen size

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      bottomNavigationBar: _bottomTab(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('View ' + type),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.print),
              onPressed: () {
                // getPermission('print');
                printPdfFile();
              }),
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
              onPressed: () {
                navigateTo();
              }),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child:
                Visibility(visible: true, child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          ),

          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.5,
              child: WebviewScaffold(
                url: weburl,
                displayZoomControls: true,
                withJavascript: true,
                // scrollBar: true,
                withZoom: true,

                hidden: true,
                // bottomNavigationBar: _bottomTab(),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          // WebviewScaffold(
          //   url: weburl,
          //   withZoom: true,
          //   hidden: true,
          //   appBar: AppBar(
          //     title: Text('View ' + type),
          //     actions: [
          //       IconButton(
          //           icon: Icon(Icons.print),
          //           onPressed: () {
          //             getPermission('print');
          //           }),
          //     ],
          //   ),
          //   bottomNavigationBar: _bottomTab(),
          // )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I am implementing webview in my flutter application.The issue is when i open the widget initially my webview is zoomed by default. I don't want it and let's say if the user want's to zoom the screen they can but by default i don't want the webview to be in zoom while opening the page.

Answer (score 0):

please bear in mind did a quick dirty code in dartPad, so maybe missing some close tags

1. How to make web-view fit into screen size
   You can use column and then expand the child

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      bottomNavigationBar: _bottomTab(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('View ' + type),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.print),
              onPressed: () {
                // getPermission('print');
                printPdfFile();
              }),
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
              onPressed: () {
                navigateTo();
              }),
        ],
      ),
      body: _isLoading   
        ? CircularProgressIndicator() 
        : Column(children: [
            Expanded(
                child: WebviewScaffold(
                  url: weburl,
                  displayZoomControls: _enableZoom,
                  withJavascript: true,
                  withZoom: _enableZoom,
                  hidden: true,
                ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
```

2 Prevent default zoom from webView

Notice there´s a variable _enableZoom, after rendering you can enable zoom. Or use another widget for the zoom [InteractiveViewer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html).

```
InteractiveViewer(
   panEnabled: _zoomEnable,
   child: WebviewScaffold(
                  url: weburl,
                  displayZoomControls: false,
                  withJavascript: true,
                  withZoom: false,
                  hidden: true,
                  ....
```